# Server keeps on displaying this and sometimes crashing for no apparent reason

Tags: java, server, minecraft, bukkit

My server keeps on randomly displaying this big wall of text when people join sometimes, ive tried deleting plugins, reconfiguring plugins, googling and i cant find a solution. It also sometimes decides to completly crash and random, displaying some simliar errors and spamming the server console. Can anyone help? I can provide more information about the crashes if people need it. I have my firewall turned off on the server and have forwarded ports 25565 (for the server) and 25465 (for the dynmap) on my router and people can join and play in the first place so im pretty sure its not a network configuration error.

For now here is the text that is displayed when someone joined and the server does not crash:

```
[20:31:05 WARN]: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:58)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:408)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:930)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:897)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.handler.flush.FlushConsolidationHandler.flushNow(FlushConsolidationHandler.java:204)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.handler.flush.FlushConsolidationHandler.flush(FlushConsolidationHandler.java:138)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:765)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:808)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:294)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:273)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.NetworkManager.dispatchPacket(NetworkManager.java:249)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.NetworkManager.sendPacket(NetworkManager.java:225)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.NetworkManager.exceptionCaught(NetworkManager.java:133)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.handler.flush.FlushConsolidationHandler.exceptionCaught(FlushConsolidationHandler.java:159)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1377)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:907)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:174)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[20:31:05 WARN]: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[20:31:05 WARN]: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:58)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:408)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:930)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:354)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:897)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.handler.flush.FlushConsolidationHandler.flushNow(FlushConsolidationHandler.java:204)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.handler.flush.FlushConsolidationHandler.flush(FlushConsolidationHandler.java:138)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:125)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:765)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:808)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:294)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:273)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.NetworkManager.dispatchPacket(NetworkManager.java:249)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.NetworkManager.sendPacket(NetworkManager.java:225)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.NetworkManager.exceptionCaught(NetworkManager.java:133)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.handler.flush.FlushConsolidationHandler.exceptionCaught(FlushConsolidationHandler.java:159)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1377)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:907)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:174)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[20:31:05 WARN]: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
[20:31:05 WARN]:        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: The error message looks like a firewall or antivirus software aborts the connection.

Comment: Yeah i know and ive looked around and everyone has said that but it makes no sense because i have no antivirus on my server, and i completly disabled the built in firewall on it and it still happend.

Comment: Hi, this question seems to be more about software in general and less about programming, which makes it off-topic for Stack Overflow. You would probably have better luck on [Super User](https://superuser.com)

Comment: @thetechnician94 Thanks i will post on there as well.

Comment: Maybe try https://hypixel.net/threads/java-io-ioexception-an-established-connection-was-aborted-by-the-software-in-your-host-machine.2881651/post-19866816 Are you or any of your users in a network set up by somebody who might have blocked minecraft or similar?

Comment: @dan1st Helpful and i have done all those steps with no difference, but i should mention that seems to be aimed at client side, im running a server.

Comment: @dan1st Even if one of my players is set up to block the connection, that shouldent be able to crash my server right??

Comment: It should not and it seems the error occurs on the server side. Did you try those steps (or the equivalets of them) on the server?

Comment: I did indeed yes, but it made no differnce, the strangest thing is, this isnt constant, it appears to be completly random weather it will happen or not, for example yesterday people could join my server and then after an hour it crashed with this error, and today the server has been online for about 10 hours and now crashed due to this error.

Comment: If you need me to provide any information, such as the server log when it crashed just 30 mins ago, i can but i would rather not because it contains some sensitive information.

Comment: You can just censor this information but are there other exceptions in the log shortly before it crashes? But note that this might even be a problem with dynmap. Did you try removing that?

Comment: Nope it is just completly random as you can see in the pastebin, ill show u a snippet just before it crashes so i dont have to censor much however the log is very long so i hope u dont mind if i use pastebin, here u go, i should mention that it is not due to the server cant keep up error as it happens when the server is at 20tps as well - https://pastebin.com/2keijY5j

Comment: @dan1st please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some reported issues to Paper. [This is the answer](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper/issues/5100#issuecomment-765588874) and see [this](https://github.com/PaperMC/Paper/issues/895#issuecomment-372175216) for furher workaround.